# Zepto Datepicker Library

Tags: date, cordova, datepicker, picker, zepto

I've decided to ditch jQuery and go with Zepto for a mobile application that I am making with PhoneGap.

The problem is that most of the date pickers available rely on jQuery (Including the one I was using before). http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Does anybody know any good date pickers that work with zepto. The only requirement is that it looks OK.

I have successfully implemented http://trentrichardson.com/ but the UI is awful and I haven't found any documentation on how to change it from using dropdowns to a standard calendar view.

I have also used the following date picker but it seems limited in that it completely takes over the input you're using and I'm not sure how to get the input to display the date once it's been selected. https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/1765620

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one appears to be working with zepto only :)
(or at least the demo includes zepto only ;) ... (with the DateFormat library, but it's optional))

http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/02/datepicker-for-twitter-bootstrap.html